# Work out SUM including Currency Symbols

Tags: php

I can work out the sum of a column by =SUM() but it won't do it if I have currency signs in there ie £, $ or € - could someone tell me how I can make it work out the sum and still include the currency symbols?

Comment: for each string, split at the currency symbol, sum elements with the same symbol, put it all together again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume you're talking about mysql. Have a look at [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

`SELECT CONCAT('£', SUM(tabel.column)) FROM table;`

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you are having $ sign in field values.

You can replace $ sign and then can use SUM function.

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',SUM(REPLACE(total,'$',''))) FROM `tbl_test`
```